# I need to add menu in wordpress using woo commerce product category?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Here I am created a code for menu.It gives an menu but cann't add product category. Help will be appreciated.thank you.

```
 // Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output          function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    // add the home link to the end of the menu
    $items = $items . $homelink;
    return $items;
    }

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create menu in word press admin menu blank menu.
Now go to function.php file (theme file) add following code in it.

You can get products cateogorty list from this function,

```
function get_product_terms( $term_id ) {

        $html = '';

        $args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term_id );

        $terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

        foreach ($terms as $term) {

            $html .= '<li';

            if( $term_id == 0 ) {

                $html .= ' class="top_li"';

            }

            $html .= '><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_cat').'">' . $term->name . '</a>';    

            if( $list = get_product_terms( $term->term_id )) {

                $html .= '<ul class="second_level">'.$list.'</ul>';

            }

            $html .= '</li>';

        }

        return $html;

    }
```

You can add products category to menu using this function,

```
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    // Woo function

    /*//product_cat
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    print_r($terms);*/
    if( $list = get_product_terms( 0 )) {



    $menu1link = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __($list) . '</a></li>';
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    // add the home link to the end of the menu
    $items = $items . $homelink;
    $items = $items .$menu1link;
    }
    return $items;

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```